# How to redirect #! urls to # from Angular 5 + Restify web app?

Tags: node.js, angular

I was using AngularJS and my routes were with #! but now, since I'm using Angular 5, they became mydomain.com/#/dashboard

What I need is, redirecting all #! routes to mydomain.com/#/ .

Because I'm having problem with users that have saved urls in their bowser caches.

I'm using Angular 5 with NodeJS + Restify server.

Comment: You cant actually redirect the /# location because it is handled by your router in the browser and never reaches the internet. 

Maybe add some code - a condition in your router's `navigate` to change the window.location.

Comment: imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })],

Answer (score 0):

Inside you routing file (You may have more that one). You just have to set `useHash:false`.

By example 
`export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {useHash: false});`

Take a look at this https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/#_hashlocationstrategy